# Content Security Policy Hashes for Files Don't Seem to Work

Tags: http, encryption, http-headers, content-security-policy, w3c

Step 1: Download a raw copy of Bootstrap 4's SHA-384 integrity listed css file, to a local web project:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

As of writing this, they have their hash listed as `sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm`

Step 2: Reference it in the `<head>` of a served .html file, as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" >
```

Step 3: Serve a `Content-Security-Policy` header that includes that hash in its `style-src-elem` policy, for the html file:

[image: Content Security Policy Header Response]

Expected Results:
File's sha-384 integrity hash matches the CSP header's hash, file is loaded and works

Actual Results (for all browsers I tested):

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://localhost:8000/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-elem 'sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm' 'sha384-iFY+dCgFnB1nmk59trTsB2i1eTLIUAg+NhcRaA3bWZAqE9HK0ZSnZdOZ9NkoAs8S'".
```

Independently I can validate that the hash is indeed correct for the file, testing through multiple mechanisms online for generating CSP hashes.

Anyone know what I am missing here? This should work, have I missed a step or misconfigured something?

C# Logic I used to calculate the hash of the file to check, and it outputs the same hash as what Bootstrap supplied:

```
private static string ComputeFileHash(IFileInfo file)
{
    using var stream = file.CreateReadStream();
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    using var sha384= SHA384.Create();

    var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var utf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var hash = sha384.ComputeHash(utf);
    return "'sha384-" + Convert.ToBase64String(hash) + "'";
}
```

I have an example repo setup here, on the branch `CSP-Not-Working-Example`.

https://github.com/SteffenBlake/Notes/tree/CSP-Not-Working-Example

It is an Asp.Net application that statically serves the html, css, and js files. It performs an initial calculation on bootup to hash the css and js files, and then adds them to the `Content-Security-Policy` header for `index.html`

You can run the application and navigate to `https://localhost:8000` and observe both the served headers and browser errors produced as `bootstrap.min.css`, `main.css`, and `notes.js` all get individually rejected.

You can verify if you like that the served file hashes are indeed correct. I even re-downloaded each file from `https://localhost:8000/bootstrap.min.css` and so on, and re-hashed them again, just to double check that perhaps Asp.Net wasn't modifying the files when it served them, but nope, the hash still comes out to be the same.

For those reporting that the browser gives hints about why the files are rejected, the error I posted up above is a complete copy paste of the error for `bootstrap.min.css`, a similar error occurs for the other files as well.

That is all the info the browsers are providing to me, at best. Firefox is even more tight lipped about it, providing even less information.

Answer (score 1):

In CSP level 2 you can only allow inline scripts/styles with hashes. In CSP level 3 you can allow other scripts by adding 'strict-dynamic' to script-src or default-src. [The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#strict-dynamic-usage) doesn't mention that you can do this for style-src or style-src-elem.

If the file is hosted on the same origin you could instead use 'self' in style-src-elem and the integrity attribute when you are loading the file to enable SubResource Integrity.

Comment: This was what I was becoming suspicious of, so to be concise: CSP level 3 doesn't support hashes for the `script-src-elem` and `style-src-elem` policies? If so, perhaps a bug should be raised that browsers at the moment don't complain about invalid policies when you pass a hash into those two. Expected behavior should be the usual error message about "Unexoected policy definition, ignoring policy xxxxxx...` but instead it "silently" fails, creating the impression a hash would be valid.

Comment: Hashes in CSP level 2 (and 3 without 'strict-dynamic') is used to allow inline scripts/styles, so it's fully valid and shouldn't raise complaints. Using 'self' and SubResource integrity should be a solid solution though.

Answer (score -1):

This code I have used to calculate the CSP hash and it works for me:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(".");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            if (fileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".css") || fileName.ToLower().EndsWith("js"))
                GetChecksum(fileName);
        }
    }

    private static void GetChecksum(string file)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            var sha = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);

            string r = System.Convert.ToBase64String(checksum);

            Console.WriteLine(file + $" \t integrity=\"sha256-{r}\"");

        }
    }
}
```

in the HTML code, you need to use this, using a script-tag as an exmaple.

so, I guess you lack the crossorigin.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. This gives the same output as my C# function, and doesn't address the issue.

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: The browser console can also give hints about why the integrity was rejected.

Comment: The error I posted in my question is the only output the browser provided, that is the complete copy paste of it.

Comment: There is no Cross Origin for this as well, the file is being served from the same domain (note how my `<link>` tag ref is same domain.

Please fully read my question and review it, as your responses are orthogonal to the problem being discussed.

Comment: Ok, one source could be CR/LF issues, that what you use locally is not what is used in production. Github changes to CRLF to LF in some cases, so after checkin, the file is not binary the same.

Comment: The hash I calculated was identical to the hash bootstrap provides for their file. The hash is 100% correct.